# Communities created via the Social Business SDK not listed under "Communities" menu options; only found via Search

Tags: ibm-sbt

After I create a Community using Java code based on the samples, I can find that Community by searching in "All Connections", but if I select the Communities menu, then any of the sub-menu options: I'm an Owner, I'm a Member, Public ... the new Community is not listed. Even after hours or days it doesn't appear. Is there a parameter in the API that I need to set, or is this a Connections configuration setting issue ?

Comment: asked Swati to respond

Answer (score 0):

Chatted with Swati...

This code works for me. 
https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/JavaSnippets.xsp#snippet=Social_Communities_CreateCommunity

What version of Connections do you have?

Did you check to see if the Community Name already exists?

This code works for me... you'll have to post your code for comment (or a sample of the code)

```
CommunityService communityService = new CommunityService();
    Community community =  new Community(communityService, "");
    community.setTitle("Test Community 1ab" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    community.setContent("Test Community updated by Update Community Java snippet");
    community.setCommunityType("private");
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    tags.add("tag1"); 
    tags.add("tag2"); 
    community.setTags(tags);
    community = community.save();
```